# Font-Awesome stack not working correctly?

Tags: font-awesome

Weird problem with Font Awesome.  I'm trying to make a larger circle around my social media icon.

If I change the first stacked icon to a size larger than 2x, it reverts back to the 1x size.

This code works:

```
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
```

This code doesn't:

```
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-3x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
```

If I use 3x or 4x, etc, the lower image gets set back to the normal size. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Using Font Awesome v 4.1.0.

EDIT - because this note keeps getting views / comments. My problem was that font-awesome only has the 1x and 2x proportions, where I wanted a much larger background image and a smaller icon (at more like like 4x).

Comment: I had similar issue with sizing and alignment when using this font-awesome feature. Using styling is the only way out I found.

Comment: I can reproduce this using Font Awesome 4.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to work as I expected it to, I changed font-awesome CSS file. At line 168, it looks like this:

```
.fa-stack-1x,
.fa-stack-2x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-stack-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.fa-stack-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Notice that the stack only has 1x & 2x options. So I added a 3x & 4x.

```
.fa-stack-1x,
.fa-stack-2x,
.fa-stack-3x,
.fa-stack-4x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa-stack-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.fa-stack-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.fa-stack-3x {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.fa-stack-4x {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

You may have to tweak a bit more to get it to line up just right. The higher the em's go, the less they line up correctly in different browsers.

But, in the end, I ended up using a border because we wanted to do something different on phone sizes, and it was simpler to edit that CSS in the @media queries.

Comment: The highest voted answer is what you should do, and not modify/override the classes manually

Comment: The problem was that there's no higher multiplier other than 2x - which is what the original problem was. Small icon, larger circle. So, the only way to fix it was to add some additional classes.

Comment: But you should not be modifying the library to do that. Adding those classes to your own custom project CSS is fine, but telling someone to go and edit the library to add the classes is very bad practice.

Answer (score 30):

This confused me too until I re-read [the instructions](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked) a few times:

*"You can even throw larger icon classes **on the parent** to get further control of sizing."*

So you leave the icons alone and simply swap *.fa-lg* for *.fa-2x* **on the parent** and the child icons grow proportionately.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: You are a legend! This should definitely be the correct answer and get way more attention! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Fairly old solution and lots of similar comments above but wanted to tell one thing I ended up doing in case anyone encounters a similar thing. I needed the the outer font to be the regular size and the inner to be smaller. I didn't feel like creating a class for this since it's only used in a single place. I ended up just adding a style class to the inner font.

```
<span class="fa-stack">
<i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x" style="font-size:9px"></i>
</span>
```

If you have a 1 off that you need something similar then you could consider the above or create additional classes to do it if you are using in lots of places. If I were to create classes, I would had done something similar to (untested)

```
fa-stack-xs {font-size:.6em}
fa-stack-sm {font-size:.8em}
```

So, they could be used like

```
<span class="fa-stack">
<i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-stack-sm"></i>
</span>
```

I didn't see in the documentation anything like this so my apologies if I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

The class fa- thin-circle-seems to only support 2x, use CSS (font-size)

```
.dimensioni_fix {
    font-size: 40px; /* EDIT THIS */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itpao25/8yPDh/

Comment: Oh, good thinking. I can just override the CSS in the font-awesome file and make the circle whatever damn size I please. Have to tweak a little bit more, as the stacking has a position:absolute in it.

Answer (score 0):

It may not solve your problem but is this the kind of effect you are looking to create?

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Because font-awesome clearly specifies 1-x and 2-x for stacking and then using larger parent classes for bigger stacks.

From: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked

*To stack multiple icons, use the fa-stack class on the parent, the fa-stack-1x for the regularly sized icon, and fa-stack-2x for the larger icon. fa-inverse can be used as an alternative icon color. You can even throw larger icon classes on the parent to get further control of sizing.*

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to make the whole thing bigger, just change the proportions between the two - so tiny icon, large circle. 

I may have made some incorrect assumptions when reading the documentation.